# What is the purpose of the Heir Hatchery?

Tags: critter-mound

So i have unlocked a new tab tab called Heir Hatchery in which i can have a Prince and Princess. they seem to breed just like the King and Queen but i need to give Sod for it.

all the How To tabs says on the matter is

> **Heir Hatchery**
>                                   You have become so rich, that you can now help a new mound get off it's feet.  However, they don't yet have their own home.  They'll need sod to create offspring.  (Sod = Score)
>                                   You can use the **shift key** to cross promote between the royals and their heirs.

but even setting up a decent King and Queen to be Prince and Princess it's costing me Sod to use and i now need 50 mil Sod to do any upgrades.

So what is the point to the Heir Hatchery?